# What is a Numb™ word?

Tags: pattern, word-property

This puzzle is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Numb™** word.
Here is a list of Numb™ and not-Numb™ words:

Numb™: **Bone**, **Fur**, **Mix**, **Calf**, **Night**, **To**, **Give**, **Sith**, **Seen**, **Sine**, **Tent**, **Tree**, **Hero**, **Tents**

not-Numb™: **Bones**, **Trees**, **Throne**, **Cosine**, **Never**, **Gonna**, **Let**, **You**, **Down**, **Rick**, **Astley**

---

The solution you provide must exhibit relation with the category name of the word, **Numb™**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might be too easy, but is it just

> words that are one letter off from a **numb**er (including fractions and ordinals), either by addition, subtraction or substitution? 
>  <s>B</s>one, F**o**ur, <s>M</s>**S**ix, <s>C</s>**H**alf, <s>N</s>**E**ight, T**w**o, <s>G</s>**F**ive, Si**x**th, Se**v**en, <s>S</s>**N**ine, Ten<s>t</s>, T**h**ree, <s>H</s>**Z**ero, Tent<s>s</s>**h**.

Comment: You have earned yourself a checkmark. Sixth and Tenth were meant to be put in context as "a sixth" and "a tenth". You'll get your checkmark when the cooldown is over.